# Bert Used for generative AI

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, language-models

I have a doubt regarding using "Bert" as a generative model. I know Bert can be used for classification or fine-tuning the question-answering. However, is it possible to use Bert to generate it's own idea. For example, Suppose I provide a sentence to Bert model like

*I spilled my drink, can you help?*

Can Bert model create action sequences for the above sentence?

Action sentences will be

1. Find a sponge
2. Pick up a sponge
3. Give it to the user who gives the command

**The given required conditions for the task**

1. There will be a robot who carries out the task
2. The map of the environment is already given to the robot. Initially, the map should be a static one.

I am not sure Bert is able to generate this types of action sequences. Any lead will be helpful.

Comment: Are you bound to plain BERT? It was not invented for this kind of tasks. Still the it could be used in a generative way: have a look at the paper BERT has a mouth and it must speak. However, other generative models may be superior.

Comment: I am bound to use some kind of generative model. If it is not Bert then what else my option is? I looked at the paper that you have suggested but in their GitHub link they mentioned about some mistake and when I clicked on this link  to see the mistakes I was redirect to Google site and the page was not found. Therefore, I am not sure is it ok to go though their implementation.

Comment: The core idea is simple: use the masking token to prolonge your input and generate the next tokens ...

Comment: Ok. What are the other possible language models that can be used to generate tasks other than Bert which is reasonable to use for my requirement?